# How to invalidate server-action cache?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I cannot wrap my head around how to invalidate server action cache.

Next.js documentation [mentions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations#revalidating-cached-data) `revalidatePath` and `revalidateTag`, but I don't see what's the relationship with the server-action.

My server-action is in a separate file called `suggestOutline`, which exports function `suggestOutline`, and I just call it from `useEffect()`, e.g.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  suggestOutline();
});
```

but past the first request, the data returned is always cached data.

Comment: update your question to include `suggestOutline` implementation

Answer (score 0):

This is example from their doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath#server-action

```
'use server'
 
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'
 
export default async function submit() {
  await submitForm()
  revalidatePath('/')
}
```

Simply speaking, request to the server action from that the defined path will be invalidated.